# Properly discontinuous action of a group

Tags: algebraic-topology, group-actions

Let $\Gamma=\{\varphi^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $\varphi(x,y)=(\frac{x}{2^n},2^ny)$. I am trying to decide if $\Gamma$ defines a properly discontinuous action on $X=(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$. I am stuck trying to find neighbourhoods $U,V$ of $x,y\in X$ that
$$\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid \varphi(U)\cap V\neq \emptyset\}$$
is finite.

I have been trying to draw it by finding a fundamental domain, so I can intuitively see how does this action work. But I can't manage to do it.

Comment: Hint: It is bounded by two rays.

Comment: I guess the fundamental domain is $\{(x,y)\in X|\frac{1}{2}x\leq y\leq 2x\}$. Althought now I don't know how to use this to show that this is an action. I also would like to determine the space obtained.

Comment: Try to verify your guess. This will help you to prove proper discontinuity and to identify the quotient space. Hint: Glue the sides of the fundamental domain.

Comment: I am not sure if I know how to do that, I can show it has no points in the interior related to each other and that for every point in $X$ exists a point in the set related to it. Although I am not sure how to start with the last part.

Comment: I think it'll look like a infinite cone without the top point. Is there any way to write this formaly?